# How to use ros with stm32f4 for interfacing dc motor

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this packages stm32f4 for ros :[stm32](https://github.com/bosch-ros-pkg/stm32) how should one interface motors using this package

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276907/how-to-use-ros-with-stm32f4-for-interfacing-dc-motor/) by [vaibhavdoes](https://answers.ros.org/users/32808/vaibhavdoes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

maybe it is more simple to communicate with your board which controls DC motors with use a serial interface(STM32 uart)?

and the chain will be:

DC motors <--> board with STM32 <--serial port with your custom communication protocol--> custom ROS node <-ros msgs- > ROS

[serial](https://github.com/wjwwood/serial) library

---

Originally posted by [0xd1ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/27403/0xd1ma/) with karma: 92 on 2017-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0